# What are the perihelion and aphelion distances of the Falcon Heavy second stage?

Tags: spacex, orbital-mechanics, falcon-heavy, celestial-mechanics

What are the perihelion and aphelion of the Falcon Heavy second stage containing the Tesla after yesterday's mission?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Musk's tweet was erroneous, and the orbit's aphelion would be nearer 1.71 AU, instead of 2.61 AU. See [Jonathan McDowell's tweet](https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/961394843648954368).

This agrees w/ orbit projection now shown in JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi): `QR= 9.86...E-01 & AD= 1.711...`

```
2458158.500000000 = A.D. 2018-Feb-09 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.688810432654559E-01 QR= 9.860573082453878E-01 IN= 1.101912591245855E+00
 OM= 3.175070416981074E+02 W = 1.772620363138233E+02 Tp=  2458153.729308890179
 N = 6.292640287243981E-01 MA= 3.002024307551933E+00 TA= 5.405918374698258E+00
 A = 1.348696130995557E+00 AD= 1.711334953745726E+00 PR= 5.720968998176613E+02

  Symbol meaning [1 au= 149597870.700 km, 1 day= 86400.0 s]:

    JDTDB    Julian Day Number, Barycentric Dynamical Time
      EC     Eccentricity, e                                                   
      QR     Periapsis distance, q (au)                                        
      IN     Inclination w.r.t XY-plane, i (degrees)                           
      OM     Longitude of Ascending Node, OMEGA, (degrees)                     
      W      Argument of Perifocus, w (degrees)                                
      Tp     Time of periapsis (Julian Day Number)                             
      N      Mean motion, n (degrees/day)                                      
      MA     Mean anomaly, M (degrees)                                         
      TA     True anomaly, nu (degrees)                                        
      A      Semi-major axis, a (au)                                           
      AD     Apoapsis distance (au)                                            
      PR     Sidereal orbit period (day)
```

The header explains the source of the data is telemetry from the 3rd stage itself, which is derived from it's GPS and other internal data:

```
Revised: Feb 07, 2018          Tesla Roadster (spacecraft)             -143205

Tesla Roadster (Starman, 2018-017A)

Dummy payload from first launch of SpaceX Falcon Heavy launch vehicle 
consisting of a standard Tesla Roadster automobile and a spacesuit-wearing 
mannequin nicknamed Starman. 

Also includes a Hot Wheels toy model Roadster on the car's dash with a 
mini-Starman inside. A data storage device placed inside the car contains 
a copy of Isaac Asimov's "Foundation" novels. A plaque on the attachment 
fitting between the Falcon Heavy upper stage and the Tesla is etched with 
the names of more than 6,000 SpaceX employees.

After orbiting the Earth for 6 hours, a third-stage burn-to-depletion
was completed at approximately 02:30 UTC Feb 7, placing the dummy payload 
in a heliocentric orbit having a perihelion of 0.99 au and aphelion 
~1.7 au.

Payload mass: ~1250 Kg

This trajectory is a ballistic propagation derived from a post-injection 
state provided by SpaceX on 2018-Feb-7, and is based on internal GPS data. 

Prediction errors could increase significantly over time due to unmodeled
solar presure, thermal radiation, or outgassing accelerations that are not
characterized.

Launched: 2018-Feb-06 20:45 UTC by Falcon Heavy (FH) from Kennedy Space 
       Center, USA (launchpad 39A)
```

Comment: I don't think that Musk would calculate it personally (maybe he could, but it is more likely that he pays some smart people doing such calculations in their entire life).

Comment: "I heard" do you have a source, or is this just gossip?

Comment: @JCRM good point, done.

Answer (score 0):

0.98 AU and 2.61 AU. See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk).

[image]

Comment: Update: https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/961394843648954368