# When is the tesla roadster expected to reach mars

Tags: spacex, orbit, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

I guess "Reach" is a bad term here.

When is the Tesla roadster expected to be close enough to mars that it can orbit it normally, just as satellites orbit us.

https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/6/16983744/spacex-tesla-falcon-heavy-roadster-orbit-asteroid-belt-elon-musk-mars

Above it says that SpaceX overshot the trajectory, and so would this have a consequence on the planned approach to mars?

The plan is to orbit mars "forever", correct?

Answer (score 4):

Elon's Roadster was never going to orbit Mars. It merely was going to go as far from the Sun as Mars is. Since it overshot, it means that it will at some point be further from the Sun than Mars. No encounter between the two was ever planned. At some point in the future, it is possible that they'll have a close encounter, however the car plus the rocket its attached to won't be able to slow down to get into orbit.

Check out [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25114/did-spacex-intend-to-overshoot-mars/25116#25116) for more details.